# REJECT Nikto Scans With Snort Rules

Tags: network, firewalls, vulnerability-scanners, ports, snort

Hoping someone on here knows a way to reject Nikto traffic with Snort rules. I've been having zero luck for days finding this anywhere online. Thanks. Peace.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Official Snort Ruleset](https://www.snort.org/downloads) then it is already included inside ruleset:

```
alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"ET SCAN Nikto Web App Scan in Progress"; flow:to_server,established; content:"(Nikto"; fast_pattern:only; http_header; pcre:"/^User-Agent\x3a[^\r\n]*?\(Nikto/Hmi"; threshold: type both, count 5, seconds 60, track by_src; reference:url,www.cirt.net/code/nikto.shtml; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2002677; classtype:web-application-attack; sid:2002677; rev:14;)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add onto what Mirsad said; if you intending to block in Snort inline mode you need to set rules from [alert to drop](http://sublimerobots.com/2016/02/snort-ips-inline-mode-on-ubuntu/). For things like scans, you need to ensure your [preprocessors](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node17.html#SECTION00324000000000000000) are properly tuned.